# Laravel - Image Uploading not working on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My code is working very well on localhost, I changed in .htaccess.

```
php_value memory_limit 30M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

Controller code is below. Given code send all data inside database like image name and extension, each and everything working fine but images is not being uploaded in respective folder.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  // Validate Data
  $this->validate($request, [
    'member'  => 'required|max:255',
    'specialized' => 'required|max:255',
    'image' => 'image',
  ]);

  //Store Data
  $team = new Team;
  $team -> member = $request->member;
  $team -> specialized = $request->specialized;
  $team -> designation = $request->designation;

  if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $location = storage_path('/app/public/images/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image)->resize(400, 500)->save($location);
    $team -> image = $filename;
  }

  if($team->save()){
    Session::flash('success', 'Team Member Added Successfully');
    return redirect()->route('team.index', $team->id);
  } else{
    Session::flash('error', 'Sorry a problem occurred while adding Team Member');
    return redirect()->route('team.create');
  }
}
```

Even following Form tag with attributes

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('team.store')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Please help me in this matter.

Comment: Any related error in `./storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: What is your `Image::class`? Also what `Storage` driver are you using?

Comment: there is no error while uploading @Quezler

Comment: @Spholt code is posted if you want any code from any file i can paste there.

Answer (score 0):

Give permission 755 to storage directory

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#configuration

Answer (score 0):

give permission 755 to which directory u have uploaded image file or if your php code host on nginx server then updated nginx configuration on nginx.conf add or update this line

**client_max_body_size 100M;**